# Trying to echo the data-id values

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to grab the data-id from a link that then opens up a modal, in that modal I want to use the data held in the data-id within a php function. 
But when I echo it I get back nothing.

I can't work out where I'm going wrong and am looking for some pointers.

Thanks.

I have the following data-id link.

```
    <div class="package-list-item">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="group-link" data-id="1235"> 
            <figure>
                <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( 12121 , 'thumbnail'); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo get_the_title( 12121 ); ?>"><br>
                <figcaption><?php echo get_the_title( 12121 ); ?></figcaption>
            </figure>
        </a>
    </div>
```

And the following in my modal - channel.php

```
if(isset($_POST['package_id']) && !empty($_POST['package_id'])) { 
  echo $package_id;
};
```

And the following JavaScript

```
$(document).on('click', '.group-link', function() {
                var package_button = $(this),
                    package_id = package_button.data('id'),
                    token = "STFXQAJ0yYLdjiYAI35hrcEZzXRplq3tQRx7EgD0",
                    channels_window = $('#channels_window'),
                    body = $('body');

                channels_window.load("channel.php", { package:package_id, _token:token }, function() {
                    channels_window.fadeIn('slow');
                    body.addClass('window-opened');
                });
            });
```

Comment: Did you mean "modal" instead of "model" in your question?

Comment: Thanks, and corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your code, You should get `package` and not `package_id` since it is the name of the parameter that you give.

```
$package_id = $_POST['package'];

if($package_id) { 

 echo $package_id;

};
```

Comment: I get "Notice: Undefined variable: package_id"

Comment: We're getting close... It now shows the data-id but with the following warning... Notice: Use of undefined constant package_id - assumed 'package_id' in /channel.php on line 10 1235

Comment: Can you past the whole PHP code please in your question.

Comment: This now works! I'd like to thanks you for your time and assistance with this.

Answer (score 0):

use .attr function to get data attribute value

```
$(document).on('click', '.group-link', function() {
                var package_button = $(this),
                    package_id = package_button.attr('data-id'),
                    token = "STFXQAJ0yYLdjiYAI35hrcEZzXRplq3tQRx7EgD0",
                    channels_window = $('#channels_window'),
                    body = $('body');

                channels_window.load("channel.php", { package:package_id, _token:token }, function() {
                    channels_window.fadeIn('slow');
                    body.addClass('window-opened');
                });
            });
```